# Quick Action does not appear to Feed Publisher of Case object in Community

Tags: community, customer-community, chatter-feed

I want to add `Log A Call`, `Email` and `New Task` to `Feed Publisher` of Case Object in Community.

In Support Settings I enabled:

- Enable Case Feed Actions and Feed Items
- Enable Community Case Feed
- Enable Email Notifications for Case Posts

In Email to case I enabled:

- Enable On-Demand Service

In Deliverability I was set field Access level equals `All Email`

I also dragged all actions to layout but they don't appear to `Feed Publisher` in Community.

My User License is Customer Community Plus.

I missed any something for show actions to `Feed Publisher` ?

Comment: lightning or classic? Did you added the Chatter Publisher component?

Comment: It is lightning.

Comment: With lightning, When i drag Chatter Publisher to lightning page. They appear but Feed Publisher in Community does not appear